Intermittent Glitch: Dropdown Displays Elements from Another Dropdown in ASP.NET Web Application
I am encountering intermittent issues in my ASP.NET web application. While it typically runs smoothly, there are times during the day when dropdowns display elements from other dropdowns instead of their own. Additionally, some users face login issues at the same time. The application starts misbehaving, but when I restart the IIS server, the problems temporarily resolve. However, the same issues reoccur after some time. I am unable to pinpoint the root cause of these problems. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Client Side Code:
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
  <select id="slcttechnician" runat="server" name="select" class="form-control js-example-basic-single">
    <option value="opt1">Select Technician</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</div>

Server Side Code:
slctproduct.DataSource = Dropdown.RNI_Fetch_Comp_Product();
slctproduct.DataTextField = "Text";
slctproduct.DataValueField = "Value";
slctproduct.DataBind();

slcttechnician.DataSource = Dropdown.RNI_Fetch_Comp_Technician_All();
slcttechnician.DataTextField = "Text";
slcttechnician.DataValueField = "Value";
slcttechnician.DataBind();

Dropdown Class Method :
public static List <ListItem> RNI_Fetch_Comp_Technician_All()
{
    List <ListItem> type = new List<ListItem>();
    using (cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_Fetch_Technician_All";
        cmd.Connection = Getconnected.getconnecting();
        using (sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            type.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Select Technician", Value = "-1" });
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                type.Add(new ListItem
                {
                    Value = sdr[0].ToString(),
                    Text = sdr[1].ToString()
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

I have attach the related code of two dropdowns where the issue occured recently , the same is happening in other dropdowns as well.

It does not appear you are returning your List <ListItem> called Type from your dropdown class method RNI_Fetch_Comp_Technician_All(). I don' tthink this is going to be your issue, however it certainly wouldn't help.
